# How to calculate the component term in BFSS matrix model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills, matrix-model

I'm reading articles about BFSS, and confused by the calculation.

The Hamiltonian is
$$
H=\frac{g^2}{2}TrP_{I}^{2}-\frac{1}{4g^2}Tr[X_{I},X_{J}]^2
-\frac{1}{2}Tr\psi_{\alpha}\gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{I}[X_{I},\psi_{\beta}]
$$
where
$$
\psi_{\alpha}=\psi_{\alpha}^AT_{A},X_I=X_{I}^AT_A.
$$
I haven't learnt the gauge field theory systematically, but I have read that the component form of a gauge field obey the same commutation relation with the gauge field. So the vector field $X_I$ act as $[X_I^A,X_J^B]=if^{ABC}X_I^C\delta_{IJ}$, and the spinor field $\psi_{\alpha}$ act as $\{\psi_{\alpha}^A,\psi_{\beta}^B\}=\delta^{AB}\delta_{\alpha\beta}$.

So, when I calculate the term$[X_I,X_J]^2$, I write
$$
Tr[X_I,X_J][X_I,X_J]=2TrX_I^2-2TrX_IX_J=2TrX_I^AT_AX_I^AT_A-2TrX_I^AT_AX_J^BT_B
$$
$$
=2X_I^AX_I^ATrT_AT_A-2X_I^AX_J^BTrT_AT_B=X_I^AX_I^A-X_I^AX_J^B.
$$
Is the calculation right?

And when I do the same to the term$[X_{I},\psi_{\beta}]$, I find that if I want to match the same answer with the paper, I need the $X_{I}^A$ and $\psi_{\beta}^B$ are commutative (seehttps://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0055.pdf). But I don't know how? I haven't found any article illustrate how the fermion matrix communicate with bosonic matrix in matrix models.

Maybe I have made some big mistakes. Could you help me to learn how to calculate the matrix model without too complex gauge theories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation is wrong. The underlying commutation relation makes no sense, as the individual components $X_I^A$ commute (they're just numbers).

Let me use fraktur indices $\newcommand{\f}[1]{{\mathfrak{#1}}}\f{a},\f{b},\ldots$ for Lie algebra indices. The key commutation relation is
$$[X_I,X_J]=\left[X_I^\f{a} T_\f{a}, X_J^\f{b} T_\f{b}\right]$$
with implicit summation on the Lie algebra indices. Here note, that $X_I^\f{a}$ are just collections of numbers. In the case of (the original) BFSS they are vectors of dimension $9\times(N^2-1)$. So they get out of the commutator:
$$[X_I,X_J] = X_I^\f{a} X_J^\f{b}\ [T_\f{a},T_\f{b}] = X_I^\f{a} X_J^\f{b}\ \mathrm{i} f_{\f{a}\f{b}}^{\f{c}}T_\f{c}.$$
Hence
$$ \operatorname{Tr}\left([X_I,X_J]^2\right) = \operatorname{Tr}\left(X_I^\f{a} X_J^\f{b}\ \mathrm{i} f_{\f{a}\f{b}}^{\f{c}}T_\f{c}\ \ X_I^{\f{a}'} X_J^{\f{b}'}\ \mathrm{i} f_{\f{a}'\f{b}'}^{\f{c}'}T_{\f{c}'} \right) = - f_{\f{a}\f{b}}^{\f{c}}f_{\f{a}'\f{b}'}^{\f{c}'} X_I^\f{a}  X_J^\f{b} X_I^{\f{a}'} X_J^{\f{b}'} \operatorname{Tr}(T_\f{c} T_{\f{c}'}),$$
with implicit summation also over the $I,J$ indices. The last trace is by definition the [Killing metric](https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Killing_form):
$$ \operatorname{Tr}(T_\f{c} T_{\f{c}'}) = \kappa_{\f{c}\f{c}'}.$$
For compact Lie algebras, like $\f{su}(N)$ which is of interest to you the generators are usually chosen so that
$$\kappa_{\f{c}\f{c}'} = \alpha\ \delta_{\f{c}\f{c}'},$$
for some (reference-specific) normalisation constant $\alpha$. With this, the trace in the BFSS action becomes
$$ \operatorname{Tr}\left([X_I,X_J]^2\right)= -\alpha f_{\f{a}\f{b}}^{\f{c}}f_{\f{a}'\f{b}'}^{\f{c}} X_I^\f{a}  X_J^\f{b} X_I^{\f{a}'} X_J^{\f{b}'} = -\alpha \left(f_{\f{a}\f{b}}^{\f{c}}X_I^\f{a}  X_J^\f{b} \right)^2. $$

Let me go further, with the fermionic term. By the way, you have a typo in your post (v2). The $\gamma$ matrix should be $\gamma_{\alpha\beta}^I$ (and all repeated indices are summed over). Anyway, this term reads
$$\operatorname{Tr}\left(\psi_\alpha \gamma_{\alpha\beta}^I [X_I,\psi_\beta]\right) = \psi_\alpha^\f{a} \gamma_{\alpha\beta}^I X_I^\f{b} \psi_\beta^\f{c}\ \mathrm{i} f_{\f{b}\f{c}}^{\f{e}}\operatorname{Tr}\left(T_\f{a}T_\f{e}\right) = -\alpha\,\mathrm{i}\ \psi_\alpha^\f{a} \gamma_{\alpha\beta}^I X_I^\f{b} \psi_\beta^\f{c}\ f_{\f{b}\f{c}}^{\f{a}}.$$

This reproduces the form of the action in [arXiv:2303.11534](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.11534). Hopefully it also reproduces the equations in the paper you're reading (which, btw you should add a link to in a v3).

Finally, note that your concern about (anti-)commutativity of the fermionic components is immaterial. You never needed to switch their components. The fact that they anticommute, comes naturally from their Grassmann-odd nature, while the boson components, as Grassmann-even, commute.

Comment: Sincerely thanks for your help! But I'm still confused about the form$X_I^A$, you say they are "a collection of numbers", and I notice that a text book says"every component of field $X_I^A$ is a vector field itself. And you say they can commute, does it mean$X_I^AX_J^B=X_J^BX_I^A$? I find that doesn't work for the fermion $\{ \psi_\alpha^A ,\psi_\beta^B\} =\delta^{AB} \delta_{\alpha\beta}$，what's the trick here?  Thank you very much.

Comment: @XinranSu I updated the answer.

Comment: I’m so grateful for your help. It was a challenging task to learn about this model but you made it easier. Now I know what 's the meaning of the signals and how to follow those calculations in articles. I have corrected the typos. Thank you!